# Passing arbitrary number of arguments to a function from a variable

Tags: bash, shell, jar

I'm trying to build a jar file with an arbitrary number of files in it which I get executing some other function. The problem is that the output is a space separated String so the `jar` function seems to interpret that as an argument an fails to locate the files. I built this simple function to demonstrate the issue:

```
makeJar() {
    touch SomeFile.class;
    touch SomeOtherFile.class;
    local FILES=`echo "SomeFile.class SomeOtherFile.class"`;
    echo $FILES;
    jar cf test.jar $FILES;
}
```

Executing the above function results in:

```
SomeFile.class SomeOtherFile.class : no such file or directory
```

However, executing `jar cf test.jar SomeFile.class SomeOtherFile.class` works. I'm guessing the problem is related to how the arguments are passed to the `jar` function and have tried to pass an array instead but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Have you changed `$IFS`? In bash, the best way to store lists of filenames is as an array, rather than in a plain variable, so something like `local files=(SomeFile.class SomeOtherFile.class); jar cf test.jar "${files[@]}"`

Comment: That's what I would expect if you were using `zsh` or some other shell that doesn't perform word-splitting on unquoted parameter expansions.

Comment: I'm indeed using `zsh`, any ideas on how to get the equivalent behavior?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE=(
SomeFile.class 
SomeOtherFile.class 
)
jar cf test.jar "${SOURCE[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

With @chepner's and @UtLox insight I ended up solving it like this since the main problem was `zsh`:

```
makeJar() {
    touch SomeFile.class;
    touch SomeOtherFile.class;
    savedIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=' '
    local FILES=(`echo "SomeFile.class SomeOtherFile.class"`);
    IFS="$savedIFS"
    echo $FILES;
    jar cf test.jar "${FILES[@]}";
}
```

Comment: Please don't combine backticks and `echo` like that -- they mostly cancel each other out, but only mostly. Just use `local FILES=(SomeFile.class SomeOtherFile.class)`